# Azure CosmosDB AutoPilot Cost calculation and estimation by hour basis?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am running an experiment on two cosmosDB with fixed and autoPilot R/U respectively. The request load and R/U consumption is exactly the same as well as all the other parameters except for the throughput setting. But there is big leap in hourly costing chart (autopilot is consuming one dollar whereas fixed is consuming 7 dollars per hour for the same throughput). I have checked all the parameters multiple times and both the experiments have exactly the same settings, however the costing chart is not making any sense.
It would be really helpful if someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

autopilot is renamed to [autoscale](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/build-2020-announcements/) now,and it has been changed.

I read an [official blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/autoscale-serverless-offers/) and there is a word in it:

"Billing is done on a per-hour basis, for the highest RU/s the system scaled to within the hour."

The reason why autoscale only consumes one dollar may be your consumption of RU/s is low in that hour.

Here is the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/).

Hope these can help you.